# sum of no. on dice appearing on dice is $n\;\;,$ where $9\leq n\leq 14$

Tags: probability

If $3$ ordinary Dice are thrown together , find the no. of ways in which the sum of the no.

appearing on the dice is $n.$

where $9\leq n\leq 14$

My Try::

Let $x = $ No. appear on first Dice

$y  = $ No. appear on Second Dice.

$z = $ No. appear on third Dice.

and $1 \leq x,y,z\leq 6$

Then we have to calculate $x+y+z = n$ and $9\leq n\leq 14$

How can i Calculate it in an easy way, Thanks

Comment: There is no very easy way, counting gets more complicated because there is an upper bound $(6)$ on the number on a die. But if we are systematic, listing and counting is not too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of patterns that you can detect as you go along.  It is easier if you know already the number of ways to get a given number from two dice, which many people know from playing games.  Let's start with $n=9$.  Let's make a table:
$$\begin {array} {c c c} x & y+z & ways \\ 1&8&5 \\2&7&6 \\3&6&5 \\4&5&4\\5&4&3 \\6&3&2 \\ \ &\ &25 \end {array}$$

Then for $n=10$, you gain a $9$ in the $y+z$ column, $4$ ways, and lose the $3$, for a net gain of $2$ ways or $27$ in total.  Then you can note that the average total is $10\frac 12$, so the symmetry says there are $27$ ways to get $11$ and $25$ ways to get $12$.

I'll leave $13$ and $14$ for you.

Comment: Thanks Ross Millikan Got it. for sum $13$ I am Getting Total $ = 21$ cases and for sum $14$ I am Getting $ = 15$ cases.